# Многострочный комментарий в VBA, Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Комментарии в тексте макроса начинаются с апострофа на каждой строчке программы, а существует возможность закомментировать сразу целый блок? Например, как в других языках - `/*` - начало блока, `*/` -конец блока?

P.S. Я нашла ответ, что

> в редакторе VBA на панели Edit есть кнопки Comment Block, Uncomment
>   Block

но я у себя не нахожу подобного:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: View->ToolBars->Edit, где-то там эти кнопки включить надо вроде бы.

Comment: @PinkTux, да, точно, именно там, нашла. Благодарю! Может, оформите как ответ?

Comment: О, пока писал ответ, уже ответили))) @PinkTux Скопируйте мой готовый ответ, а я свой удалю после этого

Comment: Да ладно, пусть так будет :)

Comment: Так или иначе, всем спасибо :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`View` -> `Toolbars` -> `Customise`

`Commands tab` -> `Edit menu`

Две иконки- `Comment Block` и `Uncomment Block`.

Перетащите из в тулбар `Edit menu`.

Profit.